# CSS clear: both doesn't clear both side?

Tags: html, css

I thought `clear:both` suppose to clear both sides of any floating elements,  when I used clear:both on box C, why does it still have D, E, F on its right side?

```css
.bigbox {
  border: 2px blue solid;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.box {
  background-color: beige;
  color: black;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px dodgerblue solid;
}

.float {
  float: left;
}

.clearboth {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bigbox">
    <div class="box float">A</div>
    <div class="box float">B</div>
    <div class="box float clearboth">C</div>
    <div class="box float">D</div>
    <div class="box float">E</div>
    <div class="box float">F</div>
    <div class="box float">G</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use clear:right; on C

Answer (score 2):

> `clear` on an element only clears the floats before it in document
>   order. It doesn't clear floats after it. The left and right values
>   mean clearance of left floats and right floats preceding an element
>   respectively. They don't mean clearing floats before and after the
>   element.

You can add your `clearboth` class in the div's you want to clear.

In your case, if you want to bring down D,E AND F. Add your `clearboth` class to D.